# Flexbox: <a> wrapper has original <img> width, not resized one

Tags: html, css, web, flexbox

I have an image, which is 1039x1039 in a link... Something like this:

**HTML:**

```html
<a href="#"><img src="img.png" alt="alt"></a>
```

**CSS:**

```css
img {
  align-self: center;

  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  border: none;
}

a {
  flex: 0 0 0;
}
```

Of course the container is set to `display:flex`. The problem is that when I load the page the img is rescaled to 80x80 but the link is 1039x80. Only after clicking the link it rescales to 80x80. It's like flexbox checks for the img width after refreshing the styles? Any thoughts?

**EDIT:** I've recreated the problem here: https://jsfiddle.net/287cLqvh/6/

Comment: I fixed it using width: 0... but still, does anyone know why it's like this?

EDIT: now other content overlaps on the link

Comment: Please include all the relevant code.  We cannot reproduce the issue with the code you've provided so far.  It seems that you have conflicting rules somewhere in your code.

Comment: Made an edit :)

Comment: your `img` is nested within the `a.img-container` element, which is in turn nested within `div.container` element that has a define height of 3em, and that's where you are running into issues most likely; however, even after checking the jsfiddle link, I still do not see the behavior you are referring to.  The image is getting its width from its parents, and the code works as expected.  My question is, do you want the image to be 1039x1039 or 80x80? Hard coding either of these values for the `img` element will do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out `<a>` is an **inline** element, so it doesn't get resized by flexbox. I had to add this style to `<a>`:

```
display: inline-block;
height: 100%;
width: auto;
```

Answer (score 1):

`flex` is a property that applies to the children of a flex container.  In this case, your flex container for your image, is your `<a>` and the children of that container is `<img>`.  In order for `flex` to work, you'd have to `display: flex;` on the `<a>` tag.

Additionally, I removed your `flex: 0 0 0;` because I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with that. I would think you'd want to just use `flex: 0 1 auto;` -- but you wouldn't need to specify that as it's the default value for `flex`.

Regardless, I think you should post the entire code that's available in order to get a better handle on what your code actually looks like.

Here's an example:  https://jsfiddle.net/qox4fa98/

You can reference this:  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Now the img is 1039x80 also

Comment: I believe I'd need to see more of the code to understand why.  I just pulled down a stock image from the internet to demo.  Did you change or remove the `flex: 0 0 0;` from your code?  I'm not sure what you took away from my answer.

Comment: Sorry it was this long... I recreated the problem [here](https://jsfiddle.net/287cLqvh/6/). As you can see the link is 1000x48 and after clicking it (img or background, doesn't matter) it resizes

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an equal (=) sign after `src` in your `img` element.

```css
img {
    align-self: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    border: none;
    }
a {
    flex: 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/469017630796296193/R-bEN4UP.png" alt="alt"></a>
```